# How to sort list items for Date field value (Apex, Salesforce)

Tags: apex-code

With Salesforce's Apex, is there any way to sort list items, for Date field value. Please refer the TODO section of the following code, thanks.

```
/**
 * Select list of jobOccurrences belongs to particular list of jobs
 */
private List<Job_Occurrence__c> getJobsByJobCode(List<Job__c> jobList) {

 // Select relevant Job Occurrence objects 
    List<Job_Occurrence__c> jobOccuList = new List<Job_Occurrence__c>();

    for (Job__c job : jobList) {  

         Job_Occurrence__c jobOccurrence = [SELECT Id, Job__c,  
                                                   Schedule_Start_Date__c 
                                            FROM Job_Occurrence__c 
                                            WHERE Job__c =: job.Id];

         if((jobOccurrence != null) && (jobOccurrence.Id != null)) {
            jobOccuList.add(jobOccurrence);
         }        
    }   

    if((jobOccuList != null) && (jobOccuList.size() > 0)) {

       // TODO
       // How I sort the 'jobOccuList' with Date field 'Schedule_Start_Date__c',   
       // for select the items according to sequence of latest jobOccurrence    

       return jobOccuList; 

    } else {
       throw new RecordNotFoundException ('Could not found any jobOccurrence for given list of jobs');   
    }                            
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really should bulkify this code, i.e. not run a query inside a loop which could cause potentially cause issues with the governor limits, and since you just want the combined list for all `Job__c` records this makes your ordering easy too — you can do it in the query!

The code you want to change is this:

```
// Select relevant Job Occurrence objects 
List<Job_Occurrence__c> jobOccuList = new List<Job_Occurrence__c>();

for (Job__c job : jobList) {  

     Job_Occurrence__c jobOccurrence = [SELECT Id, Job__c,  
                                               Schedule_Start_Date__c 
                                        FROM Job_Occurrence__c 
                                        WHERE Job__c =: job.Id];

     if((jobOccurrence != null) && (jobOccurrence.Id != null)) {
        jobOccuList.add(jobOccurrence);
     }        
}
```

Essentially we can optimise this to not only use one query instead of N (where N is `jobList.size()`) and get them ordered at the same time. First we need to gather the list of Job__c IDs, and then we can use the `IN` statement in the `WHERE` clause of the SOQL:

```
// Select relevant Job Occurrence objects 
List<Job_Occurrence__c> jobOccuList;
Set<Id> setJobIds = new Set<Id>();

setJobIds.addAll(jobList);

// get the job occurances starting with the latest, use ASC for reverse!
jobOccuList = [SELECT Id, Job__c, Schedule_Start_Date__c 
               FROM   Job_Occurrence__c 
               WHERE  Job__c IN : setJobIds
               ORDER BY Schedule_Start_Date__c DESC];
```

Finally, if you need to be able to easily map back from the Job_Occurrence_*c records to Job*_c records, you could replace the set with a map as below, though given that you just want this list I don't think it's needed here (just providing it for completeness).

```
Map<Id, Job__c> mapJobs = new Map<Id, Job__c>();

for (Job__c job : jobList) {
    mapJobs.put(job.Id, job);
}

** snip **

for (Job_Occurrence__c jobOccu : jobOccuList) {
    Job__c theJob = mapJobs.get(jobOccu.Job__c);
    // do stuff with the job
}
```

All of this code has been written in browser, so there may be some syntax errors but it should be good!

Comment: Hi LaceySnr! Thanks a lot for your valuable answer. Have a nice time!

Comment: I like the use of sorting in the SOQL query rather than in code. A slight improvement here could be to swap the loop that adds list items to the set for using setJobIds.addAll(jobList);

Comment: Good spot! Updated the sample to reflect this.

Answer (score -2):

You can try :

```
liDates.sort();
```

It's working for me.

Cheers